# Calculating image natural width on initial page load with ember-render-modifiers in Ember Glimmer components

Tags: ember.js

Prior to using Ember's new Glimmer components, I used the didInsertElement lifecycle hook to calculate the natural width of an image element. I am passing in a target width so I can resize the image in the browser.

```
didInsertElement() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    if (this.targetWidth && this.targetWidth < this.element.naturalWidth) {
        this.targetHeight = Math.round(this.targetWidth / this.element.naturalWidth * this.element.naturalHeight);
        set(this, 'width', this.targetWidth);
        set(this, 'height', this.targetHeight);
    }
    else {
        set(this, 'width', this.naturalWidth);
        set(this, 'height', this.naturalHeight);
    }
```

With Glimmer components, and using @ember/render-modifiers, the src being passed in by the parent:

```
<img {{did-insert this.calculateDimensions}} src={{@src}} width={{this.width}} height={{this.height}}>
```

In the component JS file

```
@action
calculateDimensions(element) {
    if (this.args.targetWidth && this.args.targetWidth < element.naturalWidth) {
        this.height = Math.round(this.args.targetWidth / element.naturalWidth * element.naturalHeight);
        this.width = this.args.targetWidth;
    }
    else {
        this.width = element.naturalWidth;
        this.height = element.naturalHeight;
    }
    element.setAttribute("width", this.width);
    element.setAttribute("height", this.height);
}
```

This all works fine if you reload the index/home page. However, when you **first arrive** at the site, the image is not rendered, because the value for element.naturalWidth is zero. The element is present, and if it's logged to the console I can see the values for natural width and height. Is the ember-render-modifier {{did-insert}} not a full replacement for didInsertElement?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this the "Ember" way to solve this but I've used the load event:

```
<img {{on "load" this.calculateDimensions}} src={{@src}} width={{this.width}} height={{this.height}}>
```

It solves the problem but I'm still not sure why the ember-modifer {{did-insert}} does not achieve the same thing - I had assumed the element was inserted into the DOM, and therefore you would be able to obtain its naturalWidth and height?

Comment: At the time the img element is first inserted, the image has not loaded yet. You can think of didInsertElement like document.ready for the image, and load like window.load. window.load happens after document.ready when loading a webpage.

Comment: Hi - thanks for getting back - so do you think my answer is ok in an ember context?

Comment: Hasn't this the risk of flickering UI as the image is shown and then resized after dimensions has been calculated? I would guess you need to either calculate the dimensions before inserting the image into the page or hide the image until dimensions are calculated.